# Is it possible to publish a form from InfoPath 2007 on a SharePoint 2010 site?

Tags: infopath

If I have an InfoPath 2007 form, no code, web browser compatible. Can I publish it using InfoPath 2007 on an SharePoint 2010 portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely allowable.  Check out this thread on [Technet-SharePoint 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/babf470f-d82a-4414-b07b-87edbf3303ac).

Comment: is it possible to publish infopath 2010 to sharepoint 2007?

Comment: @tehman it is possible, if you set the compability settings of your form to 2007. However, this may require then the removal of some newer controls or connections ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can publish InfoPath 2007 to SharePoint 2010 in the same manner that you publish InfoPath 2007 to SharePoint 2007.